# Background image doesn't load on my website

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I integrated a template to my new rails app. I'm using `ruby 2.6.3`, `Rails 5.2`, and i am working on Ubuntu 18.04.

When i launch the server, i see that i succeeded to integrate everything, except that the main background image doesn't appear. Weirdly, it appear when i use Chrome, but not on other browsers.

The HTML code is the following :

```
<section id="hero" class="text-white tm-font-big tm-parallax">
  <!-- HTML CODE... -->
</section>
```

The CSS code is in `lib/assets/stylesheets/templatemo-style.css`  :

```
#hero {
  background-image: url(../img/the-town-bg-01.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 375px;
  position: relative;
}
```

My image is located in this path : `lib/assets/images/the-town-bg-01.jpg`, so the first thing i don't get is that the right url would normally be `url(../images/the-town-bg-01.jpg);` instead of `url(../img/the-town-bg-01.jpg);` but when i change this, the image doesn't appear neither on Firefox nor Chrome. So i tried to create a `lib/assets/img folder` with the `the-town-bg-01.jpg` image inside. It doesn't work either.

I don't understand what is going on.

EDIT :

- If i upload my image on the web and use the link : `background-image: url(https://www.zupimages.net/up/20/02/o1ar.jpg);` it is working, but i don't like this solution i would prefer to use the image i have in my folder `lib/assets/images`, i am still trying to find a solution.

EDIT 2 :

I found the solution. In `templatemo-style.scss` :
`background-image: url(asset_path("the-town-bg-01.jpg"));`

Comment: Where is the CSS file located?

Comment: The CSS files are located in lib/assets/stylesheets/, you can see it on my Github repository

Answer (score 0):

Firefox is warning you that it could not find your assets folder files. So you probably should correct your relative path.
Also, you are miss spelling your images folder name.

`lib/assets/images/the-town-bg-01.jpg`    VS    `background-image: url(../img/the-town-bg-01.jpg);`

Comment: I know that, but when i use `background-image: url(../images/the-town-bg-01.jpg);` instead of `background-image: url(../img/the-town-bg-01.jpg);` , the image doesn't appear neither on firefox nor chrome.
In which file should i correct my relative path ? I don't understand